# What is the best way to compare values of list over a list of list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hash, bitmask

The Problem goes like:
suppose we have 3 shops and different item number are listed.
Each shopkeeper has the following items:

```
Shop 1 : [2, 3]
Shop 2 : [1, 2]
Shop 3 : [4]
A=no of shops
dict = {shop_no:[item_list]}
need = set(items that are needed)
```

And I need item [1,4], so i can achieve it by visiting shop 2 and shop 3.

So my question is how to get the minimum no of shops that needs to be visited.

My approach!!! 
BitMasking to generate all possible shop combinations, and then comparing elements.
I need a better way to compare these.

```
x=2**(A)
for i in range(1,x):
    count=0
    temp=[]
    for j in range(32):
        if i&(1<<j)>0:
            count+=1
            temp+=dict[j+1]
        temp=set(temp)
#Am generating items by combining shops and then doing a set difference
        if len(need-temp)==0: 
            return count
     return -1
```

Someone suggested me rabin karp algorithm, How can i implement that???

Comment: Are you sure whoever suggested Rabin-Karp wasn't pulling your leg?  (One of Rabin-Karp's main applications is catching people who cheat on their homework.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Comment: Its giving me TLE, The exact hit I got:
What if we can generate a unique number for every array and just store that in a hash. So now when we have to compare we can only compare that single number and save some complexity. Now the problem is how to generate that unique number for every array. There can be verious methods fot that. One of it being converting the whole array as a character and storing the array as string. Or we can also use the idea of Rabin Karp Algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my cheesy brute-force solution:

```
from itertools import combinations
from typing import Dict, Set


shops = {
    1: {2, 3},
    2: {1, 2},
    3: {4},
}
need = {1, 4}


def shortest_visit(shops: Dict[int, Set[int]], need: Set[int]) -> Set[int]:
    for n in range(len(shops)):
        for visit in combinations(shops.keys(), n):
            if need <= {item for shop in visit for item in shops[shop]}:
                return set(visit)
    assert False, "Some of the needed items aren't available in any shop!"


print(shortest_visit(shops, need))
```

It has the advantage of checking the shortest combinations first rather than brute-forcing through *all* of them in all cases, so if there's a short solution you'll find it relatively quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator together with [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) in order to compute the minimum number of shops required to buy a certain set of items:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def find_best_path(need: frozenset):
    return min(visit_shops(need), key=len)

def visit_shops(need):
    for k, items in shops.items():
        buy = items & need
        if buy == need:
            yield (k,)  # there's a single best option: just visit that shop
            break
        elif buy:
            yield (k,) + find_best_path(need - buy)
```

Testing on your example:

```
shops = {
   'A': {2, 3},
   'B': {1, 2},
   'C': {4},
}
need = frozenset({1, 4})
print(find_best_path(need))  # ('B', 'C')
```

Testing on another example with multiple options:

```
shops = {
    'A': {1, 2, 3},
    'B': {4},
    'C': {5},
    'D': {1, 3, 5},
    'E': {2, 4},
}
need = frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
print(find_best_path(need))  # ('D', 'E')
```